# VBA Excel Paste to last empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code it works fine for pulling data in. But I need more to pull in more data from another sheet to go in the last empty cell so I have all the data together.

Can I use the same code and change the name and just target the Paste to the last empty row?

```
Sub Run1()

  Set wsInfoFrom = Worksheets("StowToPrimeWest")
  Set wsInfoTo = Worksheets("View")

  lastrow = wsInfoTo.Range("A" & wsInfoTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  wsInfoTo.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).ClearContents

  lastrow = wsInfoFrom.Range("A" & wsInfoFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Set copyRange = wsInfoFrom.Range("A1:A" & lastrow) 

  copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsInfoTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

  Worksheets("View").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that you can just clone that code and it will do what you want to do **except for** the line saying `wsInfoTo.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).ClearContents`, which clears out everything from column A in the "View" sheet, so you should only do that once.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. Would you happen to know what I have to put into the code to only copy the numbers from in the previous cell and not the whole formula?

Comment: I suggest you post another question along the lines of "I have the following code [and then include your code] which copies cells (as formulas) from two worksheets to a third worksheet.  What do I need to change to copy values only?"  The answers will hopefully be along the lines of `wsInfoTo.Range(....).Value = wsInfoFrom.Range(....).Value`, but it would be too hard for me to show you exactly in this comment (and it isn't an answer to **this** question), which is why I recommend a new question.

Comment: P.S.  Obviously, you might like to try something yourself first - you might be able to work it out without a new question.

Comment: Okay thank you mate, its just I'm on a deadline for this project to be finished and this is the only thing holding me back. I've tried a few things and googled some stuff but not 100% sure what I'm looking for lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just clone that code and it will do what you want to do except for this line:

```
wsInfoTo.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).ClearContents
```

which clears out everything from column A in the "View" sheet, so you should only do that once.

Comment: This really did help me nail down what I have been working on! Thanks